# Free link checker for large website?

Tags: url, links

Can anyone recommend a free, thorough online link checker for a fairly large website?

Comment: There are many free link checkers out there. You probably need to be more specific. Are you just looking for broken links? What environment do you want to run it on? Are you hoping to run it often? Run it automatically?

Comment: Oh sorry, I just need to check this one fairly large website to make sure none of the links are broken. An online tool would be great if it's powerful enough, if not, something I could run on a Mac would be nice. It doesn't need to run automatically at any given time, and once I'm done checking the website, I doubt I'll be running it often. Thanks!

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: Mac OS X - Snow Leopard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is a SEOmoz post](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/crawler-faceoff-xenu-vs-screaming-frog) discussing the pros and cons of two different crawling tools - [Xenu](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) and [Screaming Frog](http://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/) - which check for broken links, among other things. However Screaming Frog is not free and Xenu is not online (and unfortunately does not run on Mac either). Some of the commenters suggest additional tools they use. I have used the [W3C Link Checker](http://validator.w3.org/checklink) before, but it is not very fast even for a single page. For a "fairly large website" I recommend going the way of the desktop client and see if Xenu can do what you need... if it is something you only need to check once or occasionally you may be able to find a Windows machine despite the additional inconvenience.

Answer (score 3):

[No tags, no glory](http://www.notagsnoglory.com/) is an online link checker that offers a free account to check up to 1,000 pages. Their 'PRO' edition checks 25,000 pages for $30/month.

[Nodeworks](http://www.nodeworks.com/) offers a free service to check up to 1,000 pages. (You can check once, or schedule regular checks.) If you need to check more than 1,000 pages, you can purchase additional checks on their [pricing page](http://www.nodeworks.com/prices.htm).

If you use WordPress, you might also consider the [broken link checker plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/broken-link-checker/), which is free.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your help... haven't had much luck with No Tags, No Glory, it doesn't seem to help with broken links at this time, will look into Nodeworks...